# Checking Txt File for Visitors IP

Tags: php

I want my website to check if the current visitor's IP Address is or isn't in a text file and if it is I want to assign a value.

```
<?php
$list = file("checkip.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$listarray !== (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $list));
if ( $listarray )
{
    $value = "IP NOT FOUND IN FILE";
}else{
    $value = "IP FOUND IN FILE";
    }?>

<?php echo $value ?>
```

I placed my ip address in the checkip.txt file and it ends up displaying "IP FOUND IN FILE"

I have tried testing `=` and `!==` for `$listarray` but still no luck

Comment: Try Meda's answer below, it works. Has for me, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
$list = file("checkip.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
var_dump($list);
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $list) ){
    echo "IP FOUND IN FILE";
}else{
    echo "IP NOT FOUND IN FILE";
}
```

Comment: this works but I need a variable for the if statement how do I get that part to work with a variable?

Comment: Im not sure I understand `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is a server variable, it will hold the IP address

Comment: so there is no way to change `if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $list) ){` to something like `if ( $listarray ){` after $listarray is defined?

Comment: Basically `file()` will return the list array, if you want to check if a value is in the arary use `in_array` otherwise `if($listarray)` means you are checking that the array is no empty

Comment: i still want to check if the value is still in the array but I also have other variables that i will be checking for which is why i was trying to get the if statement to work.. I have more variables that I'm checking for and I'm just adding the IP functionality to a bigger script so for example my if statement once i can get the IP part working would be if ( $listarray || $referrer || $etc ).. I'm trying to check the user for multiple things before assigning a value to the user so is it possible to assign a variable to check the array is not empty?

Comment: can you please post a new question with this specific information and send me the link. it is going beyond the scope of this question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62268/discussion-between-meda-and-joe-bobby).